# Getting going with jsbundling-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jsbundling-rails

Trying to grok how to work with js files in Rails 7 using the jsbundling-rails gem and ES modules...

In short, I want to code up functions and have them available in the page.

Here's a simple example. Working with app/javascript/controllers/application.js....

If I paste

`alert("HI");`

I get an alert in the browser so I know I'm in the right file.

Now, if I paste a simple function

```
function hello() {

    alert("hello");
}
```

That function does not appear in the compiled js file.

I've tried including the export keyword in front of the function as well...

```
export function hello() {

    alert("hello");
}
```

I don't know if it's the gem or the way I am writing javascript, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.hello = function(){
    alert("hello");
}
```